# Why won't my while loop end my rock, paper, scissors game?

Tags: python

I cannot figure out why my while loop won't terminate my game after `user_count` or `comp_count` reaches `3`.

Would anyone please be able to offer some advice? I don't see what I am missing as I have everything indented under the while loop, and I am incrementing scores +=1 with each turn that is played.

```
import random

rock_paper_scissor_list = ['ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSORS']

def comp_turn():
    comp_choice = random.choice(rock_paper_scissor_list)
    return comp_choice

def user_turn():
    raw_user_input = input('Choose rock/paper/scissors: ').lower()
    if raw_user_input in ['rock', 'r']:
        user_choice = 'ROCK'
    elif raw_user_input in ['paper', 'p']:
        user_choice = 'PAPER'
    else:
        user_choice = 'SCISSORS'
    return user_choice

def play_game(user_choice, comp_choice):
    user_score = 0
    comp_score = 0

    print('User choice is: ' + user_choice)
    print('Comp choice is: ' + comp_choice + '\n')

    while user_score < 3 or comp_score < 3:
        if comp_choice == 'ROCK' and user_choice == 'ROCK':
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif comp_choice == 'PAPER' and user_choice == "ROCK":
            print('Comp wins this round!')
            comp_score += 1
        elif comp_choice == 'SCISSORS' and user_choice == "ROCK":
            print('You win this round!')
            user_score += 1
        elif comp_choice == 'ROCK' and user_choice == "PAPER":
            print('You win this round!')
            user_score += 1
        elif comp_choice == 'PAPER' and user_choice == "PAPER":
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif comp_choice == 'SCISSORS' and user_choice == "PAPER":
            print('Comp wins this round!')
            comp_score += 1
        elif comp_choice == 'ROCK' and user_choice == "SCISSORS":
            print('Comp wins this round!')
            comp_score += 1
        elif comp_choice == 'PAPER' and user_choice == "SCISSORS":
            print('You win this round!')
            user_score += 1
        elif comp_choice == 'SCISSORS' and user_choice == "SCISSORS":
            print("It's a tie!")


        print('\nUser score is: ' + str(user_score))
        print('Comp score is: ' + str(comp_score))


play_game(user_turn(), comp_turn())
```

Answer (score 1):

`user_score < 3 or comp_score < 3` will be true until *both* scores are greater than or equal to 3. You want `and` to ensure that both are under 3:

```
while user_score < 3 and comp_score < 3:
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed to this and then it gave me an infinite loop, so I added a break command to my while loop. However now it just stops after one round of play.

Comment: @struct_python That's a different problem. Think about how many times you ask the user for input and how.many times you generate a computer choice. Does it ever change?